# Sync winform controls between threads

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, multithreading, winforms

Here is the setup.

1.) I have a form called "CallingForm" and on this form I have a usercontrol called "originalControl"

2.) I have a class called "FormLauncher" and in the class I have a public property that is of the same type as the usercontrol on the "CallingForm". I also have "ShowForm" method that creates a new STA thread and inside the ThreadStart I have a delegate that opens a new instance of a form called "ViewData".

3.) I have a form called "ViewData" and on this form I have a public usercontrol called "finalControl" which is the same type as the usercontrol on the "CallingForm" and "FormLauncher" class.

I want the user to edit properties of the usercontrol on the "CallingForm", hit a button to call the "ShowForm" method inside the "FormLauncher", and then launch the "ViewData" form with the usercontrol so that the "ViewData / usercontrol" looks just like the one on the "CallingForm".

This is a "basic" example and not the true form of the code. I have a 3rd party control that I needed to "wrap" in a middle class before launching the 3rd party control but I need to expose all the properties of the 3rd party control through the "wrapper" class.

I am getting "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

I have went as far as creating a delegate callback on the "ViewData" form and passing the 3rd party control back into it that away but then I get "Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created." So I then added a call to the "ViewData" handle before Invoke but then that just lead me right back to the original error.

--EDIT for better example.

I have a "Main" winform that we do most of our work on. I have a "Report" winform that contains a custom 3rd party report control that connects to a SQL server stored procedure. When I show the "Report" form it is taking a very long time "several minutes" to pull the data. I was told that I needed to run the "Report" form on another thread to so that the user can still do work while on the "Main" winform.

Is this true? Is there some way to launch the "Report" form without the user being stuck waiting on the form to load?

I need the "Report" form to show while the 3rd party control is loading. The 3rd party control already has its own progress bar.

We are trying to create a generic report wrapper where the user can pick a list of reports from the "Main" form and then the code will set the "Report" form source based on what was picked from a menu on "Main".

I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Don't make multiple UI threads; it leads to all sorts of problems.

Comment: As if I had a choice... This is a long running data reporting process.

Comment: @goroth: This fact alone does not justify the need for multiple UI threads.

Comment: Separate your calculation code from your GUI and then is'ts just a simple, standard Control.Invoke() pronlem. It'll also improve the overall quality of your code.

Comment: I am trying not to debate that fact of creating multiple UI threads. I am trying to ask if it is possible and if so how to accomplish the task. Basically we have a 3rd party report viewer type control that needs to be on another form that is on another thread without locking the whole screen. We also need to expose the properties of the 3rd party control to the calling form without retyping all the properties of the 3rd party viewer.

Comment: That "BeginInvoke cannot be called" issue is a timing issue that would require seeing a lot of code. No broad answer exists. And I don't buy that "3rd party needs to run on a separate thread" claim.

Comment: Maybe I am looking at this all wrong. Maybe there is some other solution that I am missing. I will edit the question to see if it makes more sense.

Comment: Could you generate your report dataset in a separate thread and then simply pass it to the report control in the main UI thread?

Comment: The report control is calling a stored procedure in the database. I am sure I could generate the dataset and then pass it to the report control but what if the dataset has millions of rows. I prefer to let the report control call the stored procedure directly from the database and let the report control do all the heavy lifting.